# GcmPubSub INVALID_PARAMETERS exception

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I've implemented GCM in my app. But some releases ago it stops recieving messages from gcm. Google says "InvalidRegistration" when i send the message via http post.

Investigation shows, that the problem is in the subscribeTopics() wich raises INVALID_PARAMETERS in latest releases. The code is

RegistrationIntentService.java

```
private void subscribeTopics(String token) throws IOException {
    for (String topic : TOPICS) {
        GcmPubSub pubSub = GcmPubSub.getInstance(RegApp.getContext());
        try {
            Log.i("KK_Reg", "Token to pubsub " + token);
            pubSub.subscribe(token, "/topics/" + topic, null);
            Log.i("KK_Reg", "PubSub subscribed");
        } catch (java.io.IOException ex) {
            Log.e("KK_Reg", "Subscribe topics error");
            Log.e("KK_Reg", ex.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

The diff between working and failed releases is shown below:

```
--- failed release/RegistrationIntentService.java
+++ working release/RegistrationIntentService.java
@@ -54,7 +54,8 @@
 public class RegistrationIntentService extends IntentService {

     private static final String TAG = "RegIntentService";
-    private static final String[] TOPICS = {"ru-konvent-reg-reg-all"};
+    private static final Object VTAG = new Object();
+    private static final String[] TOPICS = {"all"};

     private static final String gcm_reg_url;

@@ -85,11 +86,11 @@
                 Log.i(TAG, "GCM Registration Token: " + token);
                 local_token = token;

-                RegApp.setGcmToken(local_token);
+                RegApp.setGcmToken(token);
                 RegApp.sendRegistrationToServer();

                 // Subscribe to topic channels
-                subscribeTopics(local_token);
+                subscribeTopics(token);

                 // You should store a boolean that indicates whether the generated token has been
                 // sent to your server. If the boolean is false, send the token to your server,
@@ -120,15 +121,8 @@
     // [START subscribe_topics]
     private void subscribeTopics(String token) throws IOException {
         for (String topic : TOPICS) {
-            GcmPubSub pubSub = GcmPubSub.getInstance(RegApp.getContext());
-            try {
-                Log.i("KK_Reg", "Token to pubsub " + token);
-                pubSub.subscribe(token, "/topics/" + topic, null);
-                Log.i("KK_Reg", "PubSub subscribed");
-            } catch (java.io.IOException ex) {
-                Log.e("KK_Reg", "Subscribe topics error");
-                Log.e("KK_Reg", ex.toString());
-            }
+            GcmPubSub pubSub = GcmPubSub.getInstance(this);
+            pubSub.subscribe(token, "/topics/" + topic, null);
         }
     }
     // [END subscribe_topics]
```

Definitely, i can't imagine changes, which make code to fail. Please, help.

Comment: INVALID_PARAMETERS could be caused by, bad token, bad topic format (space in topic) or by using the old gcm.register method to get the token. Could you confirm that these are not the issues?

Comment: yes, i can. the problem was in `local_token`, but i can't understand why - after i've eliminated the var, everything works fine, i suppose.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are using local_token and token, but seems like something is changing local_token or token before you subscribe. I'd double check that RegApp.setGcmToken is not changing the value of the token.

Comment: It shouldn't, as i suppose `public static void setGcmToken(String token) {
        should_send_gcm = true;
        gcmToken = token;
    }`

Comment: If it works without the additional var then it is not an issue with GCM again I'd suggest to check the values you are passing around.